# Solidity How to implement fees when we buy or sell token from pancakeswap

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I wouldike to know how can I implement 4% of fees when I sell or buy from Pancakeswap ?

Answer (score 0):

PancakeSwap itself implements its fee schedule. Note that tokens can trade on multiple Uniswap v2 compatible exchanges outside PancakeSwap.

To have your own market, with your own rules, you need to start your own exchange.

You can in theory try to hack special fees into your token smart contract code, but none of the past attempts have been successful and/or they all have been scams.